# HMAC SHA256 hex digest in javascript

Tags: javascript, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to write a javascript lib to push events to Pusher.

In the environment I'm using I can't use nodejs, so no require('crypto') ... or at least I do not know of a way of using it outside node.

I'm following the example guide here: http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api; I'm stuck in the part 
where it says I should generate the HMAC SHA256 hex digest.

I am using this library http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC

So, following the instructions on Pusher i wrote

```
CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  'POST\n/apps/3/channels/project-3/events\nauth_key=278d425bdf160c739803&auth_timestamp=1272044395&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=7b3d404f5cde4a0b9b8fb4789a0098cb&name=foo',
  '7ad3773142a6692b25b8'
);
```

But that's giving me `20b132baa2aaf44ea1fab814f0788aaa44eed23a2d252c72e4dc2aaea0d6ac24` instead of `b3152b2bb5a5b0bae66435a498797aa763e9b74f86cc97c9175424f8308b2f80`.

What is bothering me is that I didn't do the "hex digest" part, so maybe that's what I'm missing, but I couldn't find a suitable lib to do this in javascript.
Do you spot any errors in what I did? Do you have a library to suggest?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: hex digest just means a hexadecimal cryptographic hash, which it looks like you are getting. not sure what's wrong though...

Comment: Yeah, so maybe it's just an error with the data I'm using, the problem is that I wrote something like this in Java months ago and it worked, with that data, so it's correct.

Comment: hmmm... I would suggest trying a [second library](http://point-at-infinity.org/jssha256/) to see if you get different results.

Comment: I'm trying it right now, thanks. EDIT: Same results.

Comment: if you try the examples on other libraries do you get the same output they do?

Comment: The two libs I have don't have tests :( will search for others

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with doing the exact same thing. Pusher's documentation should really be clearer about this issue. It turns out it's not the encyption methods. It's the order that you list your parameters. The body of your message has to be exactly formatted like this:

```
{"data":"{\\"message\\":\\"hello world\\"}","name":"my_event","channel":"test_channel"}
```

Data has to be first, then message, followed by name and then finally the channel name.

Then when you create your auth signature you have to list your parameters as so:

```
POST\n/apps/3/events\nauth_key=278d425bdf160c739803&auth_timestamp=1353088179&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=ec365a775a4cd0599faeb73354201b6f
```

So auth key is first, then the timestamp, followed by the auth version and finally the body md5.

I got it to work once I followed this exact pattern. Hopefully this helps!